# Can I detect ManyToManyField mutations before they are applied?

Tags: django, many-to-many, signals

I have a Django app that broadcasts changes of some of its models to its clients, to keep them up-to-date.
I have a separate app for that, that binds to the `post_save` signal of these models and triggers the broadcast.

Problems have come with models with `ManyToManyFields`. I am not very familiar with Django's handling of this but I understand that these fields are actually updated **after** the model is saved.

I was able to use the `m2m_changed` signal to react to the `post_*` actions and dispatch the broadcast after the object is all up-to-date. However, in the `post_save` handler, I still need to detect that the m2m field is going to be mutated, to avoid broadcasting incomplete data. How can I detect this , either in the `post_save` signal handler or the model's `save` method ? Is there a way to raise a flag on an object when a m2m field is about to be mutated ?

Here's what I've tried :

- Handle the `pre_*` actions of the `m2m_changed` signal to detect incoming mutation of the field but that does not work, because the signal gets fired after `post_save`, which is too late (data has already been broadcasted).
- Store initial values when the model instance is created, and compare them in the overriden `save` method to look for changes. This does not work because the fields are not changed and report to be == the initial value ; plus I read on other questions that this practice could cause race conditions.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Perhaps you can subscribe to the `through=...` model and thus handle the creation/update of a many-to-many relation as updates of the model in between

Comment: that being said, I'm not a fan of signals in the first place. There are several cases where updates will *not* trigger a signal: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: I agree with you on the signals parts, though I am not sure if there are better ways to handle communication here since I want to keep the "live" app loosely coupled ?

Comment: As for the "through" thing, honestly I am fairly'ew to Django and i don't know how it works. I'll look into it !

Comment: for a `ManyToManyField`, Django creates a "hidden" model that has two foreign keys, one to the source and target model, and it thus populates the m2m relation, like a junction table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: I'm however not entirely following why you need the values of that object before the many-to-many field changes. Is there a specific reason for this? After all, if you want to make an "audit tool", then you can just see it as a stream of changes that, if done in the same order, will result in the same result.

Comment: That's correct, the result is good in the end, but wrong data is sent in the way ; when handling the post_save signal. That's why I am trying to detect that sending any data is pointless at this stage, and avoid sending anything that may confuse the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally sorted this out. For reference:

**TL;DR:** The model layer is not the right place to do this ; the view layer is.

I re-implemented the notification system at the view level instead of doing it in the model layer. I made a mixin that adds notification features to my views.
Thanks to this solution :

- I got rid of signals
- I got much better control over what’s going on, which simplified the notification handler code quite a bit.